# Datecalc equivalent for Linux

Tags: shell-script, date

Am using a script in ksh to get a date 91 days prior to today using `datecalc` on a Solaris 10 server. What would be the equivalent to this in Linux ?

```
month=`datecalc -a $(date +"%Y %m %d") - 1 |awk {'print $2'}`
day=`datecalc -a $(date +"%Y %m %d") - 91 |awk {'print $3'}`
year=`datecalc -a $(date +"%Y %m %d") - 1 |awk {'print $1'}`
```

Comment: Isn't `datecalc` a ksh script? Save yourself trouble and install it on the Linux machine.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `date` like

```
date -d "91 days ago" +"%Y %m %d"
```

Though if you're just feeding it to awk to get specific fields after, you could just print the part you want like

```
month=$(date -d "91 days ago" +"%m")
day=$(date -d "91 days ago" +"%d")
year=$(date -d "91 days ago" +"%Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU `date` command to the rescue.

```
$ date
Tue Oct 20 17:27:51 BST 2015
$ date --date='91 days ago'
Tue Jul 21 17:27:52 BST 2015
$
```